# orgmode, referring to an item in a numbered list

Tags: list, emacs, org-mode, numbered

I need to refer to the number of an item in a numbered list. For example:

```
1. Something 
2. See item (1)
3. Something else
```

Orgmode lets me create **hyperlinks**, but these are useless in a printed document, so I need to refer to the **actual number** of the item. I'm not picky about how it's presented (1), <1>, 1., etc. are all fine for my needs.

Answer (score 9):

There is an example in the [OrgMode manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-links.html#Internal-links) using internal links.

The following document:

```
1. <<first>>Something
2. See item [[first]]
3. Something else
```

Will export as:

```
1. Something
2. See item 1
3. Something else
```

Comment: I have no idea how I missed this! I knew of internal links to text, which just produce hyperlinks, but didn't try that or see the example in the manual. Thank you so much!

Comment: As of Emacs 29, note that you will (sadly) have to customize `org-ctags-enabled-p` to nil, for the clicky link to work.